# Calling multiple notebook from other in databricks

Tags: azure, scala, azure-databricks

I have a total of 5 notebooks

The first is the Main class notebook. The remaining Four are sub/child Notebooks.

Let the names of notebooks be:(all are in scala language)

**mainclass,
child1,
child2,
child3,
child4**

I want to call child Notebooks based on IF conditions from the Main class notebook and execute
concurrently/parallelly.

for example:
In main class

```
var child1="Y"
var child2="Y"
var child3="N"
var child4="N"
```

I want to call notebooks which as flag as "Y" and run concurrently.

```
if(child1=="Y")
```

same for all notebooks

Kindly suggest a way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]" and [ask] and their linked pages. SO isn't a code-writing service, but we're happy to help correct problems with your code. Show us the smallest code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a notebook from within a notebook will not result in a concurrent run as u desire

Since you are on Azure , you should look at Azure Data Factory

You can build a pipeline based on the parameters you supply to control the flow of executions for each of the notebooks along with scheduling and other utilities provided within ADF

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vaebhav. Here I have if condition based on that notebook execute. Can you provide more insights?